# One to many relationship - returning only results where ALL rows in a linked table match a certain criterion without using a correlated subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following tables:

- order
- message: contains an order_id column that is a foreign key to the order table
- review: tracks which users have reviewed an order, contains an order_id column that is a foreign key to the order table and a user_id that is a foreign key to the user table
- user: tracks a user in the system, who may or may not have an assigned role; cotains a role_id column that is a foreign key to the role table
- role: tracks a special role for a given user

A message is related to an order, which can have many users that reviewed it.  Each user may or may not have a special role assigned.  I want to return only those messages that haven't been reviewed by ANY users assigned a special role.  I wrote a query to do this that relies on a correlated subquery (inner SELECT refers to message.order_id from outer SELECT).  This is legal in T-SQL but is very slow.

What is a more efficient way to write this type of query?

```
select message.id
  from message, order
  where order.id = message.order_id
  and not exists (select *
                    from user, review
                    where user.role_id is not null and
                          user.id = review.user_id and
                          review.order_id = message.order_id)
```

Comment: If this is slow it is _probably_ because of poor indexing.  Exists and not exists are generally quite optimized.  Can you share an execution plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot and let me know what you think:

```
select * from message where id not in (

    select m.id
    from message m
    join order o on m.order_id = o.order_id
    join review r on o.order_id = r.order_id
    join user u on r.user_id = u.user_id
                and u.role_id is not null

)
```

Comment: Fosco, thanks for the quick reply, but this isn't quite it.  Looks like your query should return messages where the order has a reviewer that has a role assigned.  Instead, I need messages where there are aren't any reviewers with a role assigned.

Comment: @LJ Are you sure?... The inner query does pull the message id's that have reviewers with roles, but the outer query uses that list to exclude them from the full list of messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id 
 from message 
where id not in(
    select message.id
     from message
    inner join review
       on review.order_id = message.order_id
    inner join user
       on user.user_id = review.user_id
    where user.role_id is not null)
```

In where clause I drop all messages that have any review from with role assigned.
And I think that table order is needless in this query

Answer (score 1):

Yet another take on it:

```
SELECT message.id
  FROM message
INNER JOIN ORDER
  ON (order.id = message.order_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN review
  ON (review.order_id = message.order_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN user
  ON (user.id = review.user_id)
WHERE review.order_id IS NOT NULL AND
      user.role_id IS NULL;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing query is pretty good, but the join to orders isn't necessary - try:

```
select message.id
  from message
  where not exists (select null
                    from user, review
                    where user.role_id is not null and
                          user.id = review.user_id and
                          review.order_id = message.order_id)
```